# Finding the fundamental set of solutions and expressing the functions in terms of power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

Find the fundamental set of solutions to the equation

$$xy'' + y' + y = 0$$

Express the functions in terms of power series.

---

I have found the general solution to be

$$a_{n+1} = \frac{-a_{n}} { (n + 1)^2}$$

However, I am having trouble finding the fundamental set of solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: Please ensure that the LaTex edit is correct.

Comment: You have a regular singular point at $x=0$ so you should use the [Method of Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{a_n}{a_0}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}}=(-1)^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}}=(-1)^n\frac{1}{(n!)^2}$$

Comment: I think the minus one factor has to be retained inside the product, or else pulled out as a power of minus one; please check.  In any case the Question itself is not explicit in identifying terms $a_n$ as the power series coefficients, so it would be helpful to include that identification in your Answer.  Finally a "fundamental set of solutions" should (for this singular second order homogeneous ODE) consist of a linearly independent pair of solutions.

Comment: Yes you’re right

Comment: How does this answer satisfy the differential equation at the top?